# percorrer elemento de uma classe especifica Python + Selenium

Tags: python

Olá, boa tarde!

Eu estou querendo percorrer todos os valores que estão em um span,e esse span está dentro do meu tbody por exemplo, estou tentando pegar a tag para fazer um for e interagir com todos que eu preciso, mas não estou conseguindo. da o erro abaixo:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
> locate element: .tbody

Ou seja pegar todos os span que está dentro do tbody e esse span também tem uma classe, tentei das 2 forma, mas não conseguir.

```
step_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody').find_element_by_tag_name('span').get_attribute('innerText').
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndULU.png)

Comment: Na imagem acima por exemplo, eu queria pegar aqueles valores que estão dentro do span que seria o 1,11,17

Comment: Use o `find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "stepno")`. Veja [aqui](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). Perceba que tem existe diferença entre `find_element` e `find_elements` (plural)